# IIS Express "localhost" Certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, x509certificate, iis-express

I need to test SSL on a (owin) self-hosted application.  I have been successful when I [generate my own certificate(s)](http://www.jayway.com/2014/09/03/creating-self-signed-certificates-with-makecert-exe-for-development/), and install with netsh.

However, I thought it would be useful to simply leverage the already existing Visual Studio "localhost" certificate; it is the one with the friendly name "IIS Express Developer Certificate".  Accordingly, I register it with netsh.

However, now my HttpClient invocation always fails with this exception:

> [System.Net.WebException] "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."
>   inner exception:
>   [AuthenticationException] "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."

Is there a fundamental reason why this won't work, or did I just miss something?

To be clear, I am not using IIS Express at all.  I am simply using the certificate that is normally used by IIS Express.

Answer (score 0):

By design. Neither IIS Express's certificate or the one you created are self-signed and not trusted by any party by default. Thus, `HttpClient` or any other built-in classes will refuse to connect.

If you install the certificate to Trusted Roots, then it should work fine. Or in code, you force .NET to trust the certificate via

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396